# Animating individual list items with jQuery using loop

Tags: jquery, for-loop, animation, z-index

I am trying a fairly simple animation in jQuery to get each list item to slide left in turn then drop back on the z-index.

I want to iterate through the child elements with a loop, but the for-loop function keeps incrementing the variable before the animation has completed and they all move together.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function slideLeft(cardVal) {
    console.log("sub" + cardVal);
    $(cardVal)
      .css('z-index', '100')
      .delay(1000)
      .animate({
        left: "-=450px"
      }, 3000)
      .delay(200)
      .css('z-index', "10")
  };
  
  for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    var cardVal = ".cards li:nth-child(" + i + ")";
    console.log("main" + cardVal);
    slideLeft(cardVal);
  }
});
```

```css
.cards {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px white solid;
  width: 70%;
  min-height: 50vh;
}

.cards li {
  position: absolute;
  left: 500px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

.card img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: auto;
}

.card:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 30;
}

.card:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 20;
}

.card:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="cards">
  <li class="card">
    <img src="./images/Image1.png" alt="Slide1">
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <img src="./images/Image2.png" alt="Slide2">
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <img src="./images/Image3.png" alt="Slide3">
  </li>
</ul>
```

The console.logs show me that it is going to the function correctly, but it is not waiting until it has finished running before returning to the calling function and incrementing the loop variable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In your `.animate` and `.delay` calls, add a common `queue` so they all use the same queue.   https://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the `for` loop immediately loops through every element and starts the animation.

To fix this you can loop through the elements and use `delay()` to increment their start times based on their index in the collection. Something like this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.cards li').each((i, el) => {
    $(el).css('z-index', '100')
      .delay(3200 * i)
      .animate({
        left: "-=450px"
      }, 3000)
      .delay(200)
      .css('z-index', "10")
  });
});
```

```css
.cards {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px white solid;
  width: 70%;
  min-height: 50vh;
}

.cards li {
  position: absolute;
  left: 500px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

.card img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: auto;
}

.card:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 30;
}

.card:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 20;
}

.card:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="cards">
  <li class="card">
    <img src="./images/Image1.png" alt="Slide1">
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <img src="./images/Image2.png" alt="Slide2">
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <img src="./images/Image3.png" alt="Slide3">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help